# Add Checkbox with onEdit, as new row added to Spreadsheet - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below script that adds a timestamp when a new row of data is added.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if(s.getName() !== 'Sheet7' || e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.range.rowStart < 1) return;
e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.value ? new Date() : "");
}
```

I tried the below for adding the checkbox, doesnt work.

```
function AddCheckBox() {
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange('A1:B');
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
.requireCheckbox()
.build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

I would like it to also add a checkbox as well to the column next to where the timestamp appears.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just worked it out if anyones interested

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if(s.getName() !== 'TEST' || e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.range.rowStart < 1) 
return;
e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.value ? new Date() : "");
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C1');
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
.requireCheckbox()
.build();
 cell.setDataValidation(rule);
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();   
 spreadsheet.getCurrentCell()
 .getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange()
 .autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  }
```